# Change form action onchange selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am struggling with following. Simplified I have a database with two tables
Table clients with client 
Table projects with client, project

I have a form with a dropdown list of clients. Onchange of a selected client, through function fetch_select(val) and fetch_data.php a second dropdown list of projects is populated. 
This works fine.

I have added to each dropdown list a final  to add a new client or project. In both dropdown lists the "add" option is listed at the bottom as desired.
Tricky is now how to change the onchange at the moment that "add" is selected. 
In this case I want a modal window to pop-up so I can add a client or project, which disappears on a submit, so the user will return were he or she was.

In vain I have tried to build an if statement in the function fetch_select(val) so it will no start fetch_data.php when the content of the client is "add_client"

Below is the code I use:

File index3.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include 'dbconnect.php';
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch_select(val)
{   
 $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 url: 'fetch_data.php',
 data: {
  get_option:val
 },
 success: function (response) {
  document.getElementById("projects").innerHTML=response; 
 }
 });
}
</script>

<?php
echo "<table>";
echo "<form action='index3.php method='post'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<select name='client' id='client' onchange='fetch_select(this.value);'>"; 
echo "<option>Name of Firm</option>"; 
$select = mysqli_query($Verbinding,"SELECT client FROM clients GROUP by client");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) 
    {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['client'].'">'.$row['client'].'</option>';
    }
echo "<option value='add_client'>Add Client</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<select name='project' id='projects'>";
echo "<option>Select Project</option>";             
echo "</select>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

File: fetch_data.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
{
include 'dbconnect.php';
$client= $_POST['get_option'];
    {
    $find = mysqli_query($Verbinding,"SELECT * FROM projects WHERE client='".$client."'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($find))
        {
        echo "<option value='".$row['project']."'>".$row['project']."</option>";
        }
    }
    echo "<option value='add_project'>Add Project</option>";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Hope that anyone can help me out. Thanks and regards,

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood, this seems fairly straightforward:

```
function fetch_select(val)
{   
  if (val != "add_client")
  {
    $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'fetch_data.php',
     data: {
       get_option:val
     },
     success: function (response) {
      document.getElementById("projects").innerHTML=response; 
     } 
    });
  }
  else
  {
    //code here to show your popup
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ADyson for your quick response. The if else stament works, so that's a first step. However, I can not manage to get the modal window to show. I have added a css style sheet.

Comment: no problem. This answer solves your problem, so if it's helped please mark as accepted, thanks :-). In terms of adding a modal, we can't really help you until you show the HTML/CSS/Script you've got so far - probably it deserves a separate question, as it's really a separate problem.

Comment: P.S. if you link to your new question here, i will try and help

Comment: See new thread on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279068/opening-modal-from-dropdown-list-to-add-client